# How do I Import an Adobe Animate file with a transparent background into After Effects

Tags: animation

I've created a frame-by-frame animation in Animate and have exported the file with an alpha channel so the background is transparent, but when I import the MP4 file into After Effects, the file has a black background.  I haven't exported it yet because I have a lot more editing / animating to do on this project, but can anyone tell me how to make the background clear so the animation fits to the background I have created on After Effects.  (I've tried to import the Animate file but it doesn't work as I know this may be a way around it.)

Answer (score 0):

To export out a video so it has an alpha channel! I hope, You need to export the file as an SWF file and I hope it'll work for you!